# Working with a list of checkboxes in an ASP.Net MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three tables in my database: **Pages**, **Tags** and **Joiner**

My entities look like this (abbreviated)...

```
public class Page
{        
    public int PageId { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{        
    public int TagId { get; private set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Each page can have any number of tags, and each tag can be applied to any number of pages, hence the **Joiner** table for the many-to-many relationship.

On the Edit view for the Pages controller, I want the user to be able to update the title and body, as well as select any of the tags from the tags table in the form of a **list of checkboxes**.

For example, if ten tags exist in the tags table and the current page has two tags in Page.Tags, then ten checkboxes will be displayed with two of them ticked. The user can then change the selection and save the page, and the joiner table will get updated.

What is the best way to do this? I am happy with the database update code, it's the View code that I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that:

First, define a viewmodel like this:

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public Page pageToEdit{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

Then, in your controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    PageViewModel model = new PageViewModel();
    model.Tags = yourRepository.SelectTags();
    model.PageToEdit =  yourRepository.SelectPage(id); 
    return this.View(model);
}
```

in your View inherits `ViewPage<PageViewModel>`
 and the content must looke like this:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()){ %>

[...] 
<%
foreach(Tag tag in Model.Tags)
{
      Response.Write(Html.CheckBox("tagId_"+tag.TagId,Model.PageToEdit.Tags.Select(t=>t.TagId).Contains(tag.Tagid));
}
%>
[...]
<% } %>
```

Comment: That looks excellent, thanks. I hadn't thought of creating a new class - good idea. Is this a common technique?

Comment: Yes it is common: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx

Comment: what if u need that product will be related to many categories (many-to-many), in this case u need to get ids and not true/false, so how can i do it?